# How does the Commando / Axton's Phalanx Shield work?

Tags: borderlands-2

[Phalanx Shield](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Phalanx_Shield) is a tier 3 skill in Axton / the Commando's Survival skill tree. It is described as:

> Your Sabre Turret projects a Protective Shield. The Shield attempts to block enemy ranged attacks, but lets friendly ranged attacks pass through. Enemy movement and melee attacks are not affected.

I am curious if it works like the player character's shield.

- Do shock element attacks deal more damage to it?
- Do [elemental damage modifiers](http://borderlands2.gamepedia.com/Elemental_Effects#Elemental_Damage_Multipliers_-_first_playthrough) for the other elements affect it too?
- Does it also recharge?

Comment: I'm guessing it works similarly to the ION Loader's shield, but I've never seen Axton's in action.

Comment: I've been playing with a commando that has this skill since the first time you could get it, and I don't think I can answer all your questions :)  It does recharge, it's not particularly strong (it goes down quick under concentrated fire), but it does protect you for a short period.

Comment: Also, if you have the 2 turret ability, both get their own shield.

Comment: Voting to reopen. I removed the question that is related to the capacity of the Phalanx Shield (which I agree is already asked about in [that other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94354/how-much-shield-does-phalanx-shield-provide-for-axtons-turret)), and the remaining questions here are unanswered and is not asked about in that other question.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested the Phalanx Shield on my commando and I don't think shock elemental attacks deal more damage. I do know that other elemental damage modifiers do not affect it in any way. The shield recharges with each use of the Sabre Turret.

Comment: How did you test it?

Comment: I've tested it against a group of bandits and nomads. The Nomad Pyro's fire attacks didn't deal extra damage for their incendiary.

Comment: @Sean Does it recharge in the same way as the player character's shield? i.e. Once depleted, will it recharge if the turret has not been hit for some time?

Comment: @galacticninja; I have a 61 axton and have been using the shields since about lv 30 and no, the shield will not recharge after going down even if there is no damage taken. Phalanx Shields are up once per use of turret, per turret (i.e., use 2 turrets, get 2 phalanx shields). When the action skill cools down and you use the turret(s) again the shield(s) will be back.